# EDAMUserException: LIMIT_REACHED errorCode:6

Tags: python, api, exception, evernote

I'm using the evernote api [python sdk](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python) and I keep getting this exception:

`EDAMUserException: LIMIT_REACHED: {"errorCode":6,"parameter":"Note"}`

Does anyone understands what this limit refers to? Is there a limit on creating notes through the api!? The sdk is very uninformative and I couldn't find some description about it elsewhere.

Appreciate your help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting Evernote support, it turns out that LIMIT_REACHED exception can happen in two cases:

- The first one is the note being created is too large as [kungphu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/833881/kungphu) suggested.
- The second case is the total number of notes in the account is reached (100k notes for individual account).

The latter was the cause for me, deleting Trash notes fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Evernote's [error code documentation](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/Errors.html#Enum_EDAMErrorCode) defines `LIMIT_REACHED` as indicating you're trying to create a note that's too large.

From the [error handling documentation](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/error_handling.php):

> **Maximum note size**
>
> The Evernote web service limits the maximum size of an individual note. Calls to NoteStore.createNote and NoteStore.updateNote can fail if the new size of the note would be larger than the maximum allowed. In this case, an EDAMUserException will be thrown with the error code LIMIT_REACHED and a parameter value of Note.size.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Contacted their support and the reason was the total number of notes reached.